# How to successfully claim App, now that Facebook/Meta has deprecated Admin role

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

Meta has made a change such that the admin of an App can no longer do most functions.

You now must create a Business Account, and then "claim" the app there, so that you can assign permissions.

I created a business account. I made sure that the email address at the company domain was verified and matching on the app and on the business account.

But when I try to claim an app it gives an error:

***Unable to claim (AppID)***

***You're not able to add this app. Either you're not an admin of the app or it's owned by another business.***

Answer (score 0):

I solved with selection "No Business Managager account selection"